# How to setup same GIT repository for development, build and production

Tags: magento2, git, deploy, deployment

As stated in [Magento Docs for Development System](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/development-system.html) and in [Magento Docs for Build and Production System](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/build-system.html) (Quote from Build Server explanation):

> All Magento code is under source control in the same repository as the
>   development and production systems

Then there are two different `.gitignore` files ([Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/config-reference-gitignore.html)), one for development, and for for build and production.

I am struggeling to keep up with that. How to keep everything in the same repo, but use different `.gitignore` files?

On [Build Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/build-system.html), they explain it this way:

> 2. Retrieve the Magento code from source control.
> 3. If you use Git, open `.gitignore` in a text editor.
> 4. Start each of the following lines with a # character to comment them out: 
>      [...]
> 5. Save your changes to `.gitignore` and exit the text editor.
> 6. If you use Git, use the following commands to commit the change:
>
>    `git add .gitignore && git commit -m "Modify .gitignore for build and production"`

So, wouldn't this effectively change the `.gitignore` file also for the development environment? There are using the same repo.

Answer (score 0):

Please Create 3 separate branch development, build and production in GIT repository.

When we Create a new GIT repository with  git init repository has olny master Branch.follow below stept to create new branchs

**1.Check Avaible Branch and current Brach run below command**
 git Branch

Output like will like below
* development
  master
  staging

Here * development is cuurent branch, now Swich to master brach with run command git checkout master

**2.Create a New brach Name 'build' from Master with run below command**

```
git checkout -b build
```

**3.Create a New brach Name 'development' from build run  below command**

```
git checkout -b development
```

Note:Update your code changes into development branch with add, commit and push command then merge your 'development' Branch with Branch 'build'. now checkout to build branch and run git pull origin build command

After merge your 'build' Branch to Branch 'master'. now checkout to Master branch and run git pull origin master command

For more information please check https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches